# Calculate total supply of XTZ for a given block

Tags: tezos-client, rpc, api, circulating-supply

I want to build a real-time Tezos yearly/monthly inflation calculator that updates for every block. While I have the rewards calculation under control I don't know how to calculate the total XTZ supply. I am aware that tzscan returns this value but want to calculate it myself with nothing more than the Tezos node RPC if possible. What are the steps to do this?

Comment: do you have any formula to calculate the reward for each block or any api which gives the reward of the block. I have my own tezos node and when i query 
  http://IP:port/chains/main/blocks/417645//header this does not give me the rewards info

Answer (score 2):

The protocol by itself does not track that number (though it would be useful if it did, for many reasons).

This leaves one option, use an indexer that tracks the total supply, and updates it block by block by analyzing how many tokens were created, and how many were burned.

Comment: Sounds great but how to compute it? I don't see anything in the genesis block operations for example.

Comment: What indexers exist for this purpose?

Comment: It is something that is on the agenda of everyone. I hope Cryptium Labs will implement this asap so that inflation can remain a constant %. It is in the interest of the whole network to do this. I know some work has already been done but it has not yet been implemented.